# Azure Resource Manager all function 'resourceId' arguments must be string literals error

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am getting the following error when implementing ARM template with availability set  *'/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/mgRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myVM'*. "Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': **all function arguments must be string literals**"

```
"availabilitySet": {
                    "id": "[resourceId(subscription(),parameters('RGName'),'Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets',variables('ASName'))]"
```

I tried to remove **subscription()** from parameters, didn't help. I have to keep parameters('RGName') because it is not current Resource Group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is what it is, it only accepts strings.

1. subscription() would return an object, not a string.
2. Since you are using subscription() it means you are targeting the same subscription, you can just drop this part.
3. parameters('RGName') - is only needed if the resource is in another resource group. It has to be a string as well.
4. variables('ASName') - has to be a string as well.

If it complains something is not a string, then something is not a string :)

Comment: Right, better after remove subscription(). But now "Entity resourceGroupName in resource reference id /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/myRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/myAS is invalid while this is exactly correct resource ID, compared char by char

Comment: i think its not supported: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778323/can-i-put-vm-into-another-resource-group-than-availabilityset